# Vba excel procedure

Tags: excel, vba

I created a vba procedure that opens a excel file, update with SQL and closes it automatically at a specific hour. The problem is that when I open the file to see it I have no access because  it closes automatically all the time. What can I do?

Comment: Post the procedure and any code that may be in the workbook you open.

Comment: you need to set a variable when vba opens the file. then on close, check that variable, only close if true, i.e. opened by vba...

Answer (score 0):

From Windows Explorer: Hold down the shift key, right click on the file and choose "Edit" or "Open" - keep the shift key down until it's loaded.

Alternatively use this code in a separate excel file

```
Sub OpenFile
Application.EnableEvents = False
Dim s As String
s = Application.GetOpenFilename("*.xls,*.xls", , "Choose File")
Workbooks.Open s
Application.EnableEvents = True
end sub
```

to open the file without running any code in it.

Comment: Thank you very Much. Muito Obrigado pela ajuda.